# Blue Screen, unable to boot into Windows Safe Mode to fix the issue

Tags: boot, bsod

When I attempt to boot into Windows get a Blue screen. The information displayed says "kmode_exception_not_handled."

When I turn on my pc the blue screen appears and then the computer automatically restarts only to return to the blue screen. I cannot access Windows.

The blue screen appears before windows fully boots. I have created a bootable windows drive using the windows media creation tool, but I am not sure how to boot into window safe mode from the usb drive.

I have tried entering safe mode by booting up the windows media, clinking repair your computer, clicking advanced options and then going to the command prompt option. I tried accessing windows safe mode via the command prompt by using the command "*bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal*" but I keep getting a message that says "the boot configuration data store could not be opened."

Could someone help me boot into safe mode so I can fix this problem.

Comment: Get the disk manufacturer’s drive test App on bootable USB key and test the drive. You may have a drive problem here